# SQL refer a to b and b to a

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm using PHPMyAdmin (so mySQL) to create this.

I have 2 tables, Album and photo.  Of course, a photo can be part of an album and for that I use a foreign key from photo to album.

But now I want to be able to put a photo in the album table so I can use that photo as a cover for my album. I've tried adding a foreign key but that gives me a foreign key constraint.

Here are the tables to help understand what I mean (foto = photo). The red line indicates what I want to achieve.

[image]

I'm not that good at SQL so any help is appreciated.

SQL Album:

```
CREATE TABLE `Albums` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Album_Naam` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Aanmaakdatum` datetime NOT NULL,
`FotoID` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
KEY `FotoID` (`FotoID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

SQL Photo

```
CREATE TABLE `Foto` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Foto_Naam` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`AlbumID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
KEY `AlbumID` (`AlbumID`),
CONSTRAINT `Foto_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`AlbumID`) REFERENCES `Albums` (`ID`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Why not just add a column in the photos table ```tinyint(1)``` where 1 = album cover, and 0 otherwise. Better yet, add a column to albums with the key of the cover photo. You might want to have a couple of triggers that clear that column if the related photo record is deleted or if the album id is changed for that photo.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Yeah i could do that. Is my way of doing it wrong or just bad practice?.

Comment: You can make the "album cover" optional by making `Albums.FotoID` nullable; allowing you to insert an empty album, and later set the reference to its "cover". (Personally, I'd stay away from the "cover flag" on photos; it's not a horrible idea or anything, just not keen on the idea of a flag field that can't be constrained.)

Comment: @Uueerdo Post the details of that as an answer.

Comment: @Uueerdo It is nullable i now have a problem with the reference part.

Comment: @JariFlederick add the DDL (the CREATE statements) for the tables to the question.

Comment: Old style physical photos could only be in a single album.  Each modern digital photo could be in any number of logical albums.  Unless you really want to restrict thinking to the physical style — and even then, you could have multiple prints from a single negative that are in separate albums.   Just to add to the fun of life.  Can an album have no photo on the cover?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It can because it has a default value taht refers to a default image on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreign key can be made optional by making the referencing field nullable; NULL values in the field do not violate the foreign key constraints enforced on it. This can be used to represent purely optional relations or, as in the case of this question, defer setting the value in semi-cyclic dependencies.

Note that to remove the cover photo from an album, the album will first need it's cover reference to that foto set to another photo, or to null. Similarly, to delete the album, you would need to delete it's `Foto`s, and so first set it's cover to null.

Comment: The fact you've defaulted it to '1' might be causing you some issues if Foto.ID 1 does not yet exist. I believe MySQL uses the default value when you try to insert NULL or ignore the field on an insert.